# How to check thread group stopped execution in jmeter

Tags: testing, while-loop, jmeter

I have two thread groups.

```js
Thread group1: 
  http request
    csv data set configure -> stops when reached end of file
    
Thread group2:
  while loop
    http request
      csv data set configure -> reiterate when reached end of file
```

Both the thread groups run in concurrent manner, I want to stop the thread group2 when the thread group1 finished execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend your configuration as follows:

- Thread Group

  - [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) in the "Loop Count" section:

    ```
    ${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().size(),)}
    ```

    - HTTP Request

      - CSV Data Set Config
  - [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler configured as follows:

    [image]

This way HTTP Request will be executed as many times as the number of lines in the `test.csv` file, then test will proceed to Flow Control Action sampler which will stop the test

Comment: Exactly, flow control action is the one i am looking for. Thank you Dmitri